# What is the recommended way to add index signature to a function defined in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Let us say I have a function el, defined in typescript:

```
function el():string { .. }
```

I would like to remove the type violation (has no index signature) when later adding keys to el:

```
el.x = () => {...}
```

Is this possible to do without casting to any ?

So far the best solution I have found is to define a separate interface and casting to it while assigning:

```
interface ElFactory {
  [index: string]: () => string
  (): string
}
```

And then:

```
(el as ElFactory).x = () => {}
```

Is it possible to avoid the casting entirely ? As in, while defining the function associate it with the interface or specify the index signature while defining the function ?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are looking for. Could you provide some example? For me currently it looks like you want to extend a `Function` type?

Comment: I want a variable el which can be invoked as a function `el()` and which has function members `el.x()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your function to the interface when it is created:

```
interface ElFactory {
  [index: string]: () => string
  (): string
}

var el = function (): string {
    return "test";
} as ElFactory;

el.test1 = () => "22"; // works
el.test2 = "22"; // error
```

Prior to TypeScript 2.2 you will have to use the bracket notation to define properties for this to work:

```
el["test1"] = () => "22"; // works
el["test2"] = "22"; // error
```

Comment: FYI: `el.test1` and `el.test2` would work just fine since TypeScript 2.2.

Comment: Nice. I was testing at http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ which must have an old version running.